# How to manage form state with Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a dynamic elements based on JSON file. There would be multiple type of elements e.g. "text, text input, datePicker, dropdown etc." how can I use Formik to manage form state for each created element. here is my code!

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.itemstorender.map((item) => {
          console.log(item.element);

          if (item.element == "TextInput") {
            let i_id = item.id;
            console.log("Ids : ", i_id);
            return(
                <TextInput
              key={item.id}
              placeholder={item.label}
              onChangeText={(value) => this.addValues(value, i_id)}
            />
            )
          }
          else if (item.element == "DatePicker") {
            let i_id = item.id;
            console.log("Ids : ", i_id);
            return(
               <DatePicker
               
                style={{ width: 200 }}
                date={this.state.cdate}
                mode="date"
                placeholder="select date"
                format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                customStyles={{
                  dateIcon: {
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: 0,
                    top: 4,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                  },
                  dateInput: {
                    marginLeft: 36,
                  },
                  // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
                }}
                onDateChange={(dates) => {
                  this.setState({ cdate: dates });
                }}
              />
            )
          }
        })}
        <View>
          <Button title={"submit"} onPress={() => this.getValues()} />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below but there are more things to be get done here.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

export default class MyFormScreen extends React.Component {

  renderForm = ({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values }) => {
    return (
      <>
        {
          this.state.itemstorender.map((item) => {
            // your dynamic form
            if (item.element == "TextInput") {
              return (
                <TextInput
                  key={item.id}
                  placeholder={item.label}
                  value={values[item.field]} // must be like email, password, firstname, lastname etc
                  onChangeText={handleChange(`${item.field}`)}
                />
              )
            }
            ...
          })
        }
        <View>
          <Button title="submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
        </View>
      </>
    )
  }

  getInitialValues = () => {
    const initialValues = {};
    this.state.itemstorender.forEach(item => {
      initialValues[item.field] = '' // set condition here if required
    });
    return initialValues;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={this.getInitialValues()}
        onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
      >
        { this.renderForm }
      </Formik>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Nazeer Bin Zafar, I have tried your solution but it give me this error. "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops"

Comment: let me see your implementation. Why are you doing setState when formik does it using handleChange.